# Windows: "Your computer is low on memory" with 62% of memory usage

Tags: java, windows, memory

I've upgraded my workstation from Win7 (actually Win Server 2008 R2) to Win 10 and now I'm experiencing very strange behavior - system says "Your computer is low on memory" during actually low memory usage, 60-70% is used out of 16GB (i.e. 4-6GB is displayed as free) - see the screenshot.

Any idea why is this happening?

Not sure if it relates some-how - in 90% of cases the process Windows wants to close is "Java", in some cases it is "Chrome".

This is a development workstation and potential "memory users" are - java app server (up to 6GB), InteliJ IDEA (~1GB) + Mongo DB.

[image]

Comment: This question may be a better fit for Super User.

Comment: «Windows: "Your computer is low on memory"» is a tautology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But your computer *is* low on memory.

Whats confusing you is the value the task manager reports as "free memory", thats physical memory. The thing to know is that processes allocate memory from the virtual memory pool.

A process can *allocate* but not immediately *use* memory from the OS. But with allocation comes a guarantee to the process that it can use the amount of memory allocated *at any time*.

Look at the value for "Committed: 17.5 / 17.9 GB". The programs you are running have allocated almost all your (virtual) memory, but they don't actually use all of that memory at the moment. Windows can not *predict* or know when or if they are going to make use of that memory, so it warns now.

The simplest solution is to increase the amount of virtual memory available: Enlarge your page file. You do not need more RAM, as long as a sufficient amount remains free.

Comment: I've seen these numbers "Committed: 17.5 / 17.9 GB", but I did not have reasonable  description for them - thanks now I have. And yes - it is really confusing - in Win7 task manager displayed 'virtual memory' on the memory graph instead of 'Physical'  as it does now, so getting out of virtual memory was obvious previously. Additionally - there is no 'virtual memory' column on 'Details' tab - so it is not possible to trace who is eating much of VM :(.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you downloading [ReimagePlus](http://www.reimageplus.com/includes/router_land.php?tracking=ReimageNetworkCon&dis=med&exec=run&lpx=rvb&banner=Guyava&adgroup=med&ads_name=DD)
. It repairs most computer errors and protects you from file loss. It's certified by Windows.

Other recommendations:

Usually, the “Your Computer is low on memory” Windows message will be displayed when there are lots of processes running or when your programs are using too much memory. In this case your RAM memory will not be able to support all the processes and you will be prompted to make some changes in order to disable some of your programs. Well, that’s exactly what you should do – of course remove only the processes that aren’t important for you as if you end up a system process you can damage the Windows  software.

Therefore, launch Task Manager on your device – you can do this by right clicking on your task bar and by selecting the option dubbed as “Start Task Manager”. Then from the Task Manager main window select the Processes tab and click on “Memory (Private Working set) in order to sort your processes by memory usage. From there just remove or end the processes that are using too much memory. This should resolve your problems.